# How to convert Java array received a PlayFramework view to javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, playframework

I have two Java objects of the form:

```
List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(2);
    add(4);
    add(8);
}};
```

And:

```
List<String> alphaList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("two");
    add("four");
    add("eight");
}};
```

And rendered to a PlayFramework view called `index.scala.html` using:

```
return ok(index.render(numberList, alphaList));
```

I must manipulate these arrays within a javascript script in `index.scala.html`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using

```
var javascriptVariable = @javaVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var numList = @numberList
var aList = @alphaList
```

This turns them into javascript arrays.